# Implementing OnClickListener to list items of a list

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, onclicklistener

I used list view to list the items of my SQLite database as follows:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
db.open();
Cursor c = db.getAllHistory();
ArrayList<String> temparr = new ArrayList<String>();
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        temparr.add(c.getString(0)+'\t'+c.getString(1)+'\t'+c.getString(2)+'\t'+c.getString(3)+'\t'+c.getString(4)+'\t');
    } while(c.moveToNext());
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, temparr);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
} else {
    db.close();
}
```

Now I want to access the specific list item by using OnItemClickListener. How should i do it?

Comment: you mean listview.setOnItemClickListener ?

Comment: yes. I did listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
      
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    
    
   } 
       });
but now i m stuck how to extract items over there. Actually I did not understand how it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get your perticular data-

Implement setOnItemClickListener()-

and `position` will return list's item position number:-

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        String yourData = temparr.get(position);
   }
});
```

Comment: while displaying items I want to display it by in a screen rather than in a toast, can u edit the above code showing the implementation?

Comment: If you want your data to display in another screen then you have to create a new activity. Then pass your data threw intent.

Answer (score 2):

Just call `listView.setOnItemClickListener()` with your implementation of the listener.

Comment: I did it. But since i m new to android programming. And i m confused about how it works. Can you explain it a bit please

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? What do you need explained?

Comment: here is the first example google spits out for me:  http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1351248

Comment: actually i was getting an error message on OnItemClickListener and it asked me to declare a class which I had already created and when i clicked add unimplemented methods. The error dissapeared itself creating the same method i had wrote earlier. I still don't know the problem but my problem is solved. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
       // your code
       // Toast.makeText(context,temparr.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
});
```

parent ->   The AdapterView where the click happened.

view -> The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)

position -> The position of the view in the adapter.

id->The row id of the item that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

**You can set the listener like this:**

Put this code in `onCreate()`

```
TextView disp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                 String temp = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                 disp.setText(temp);// display on screen
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**

As you want to display the listItem on screen in a permenant sort of way rather than displaying a toast, the easiest way that you can do this is by adding a TextView in your layout. See the updated code

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually it helps. While displaying items I want to display it by in a screen rather than in a toast, can u edit the above code showing the implementation?

Comment: It works. But the problem is the text overlaps with the existing text. I want display the result on another screen.